# vmware and licensing

Tags: licensing, vmware

If I have a windows xp computer with a single license (the one dell gave me), if I have 2-3 vm's setup (using vmware) for development purposes, do I have to have licenses for all of them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Licensing question when running Windows XP under Windows XP (using vmware)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759110/licensing-question-when-running-windows-xp-under-windows-xp-using-vmware)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2):

Read Microsoft's EULA that came with the OEM license you have.

It most likely says you can only have one copy running at a time. So, yes: you need multiple licenses.

If you're doing development at a company or school, you may be able to use a volume/site license key, however.

Comment: This is true. One thing to note is that the volume license "loophole" has been closed for OS versions Vista and afterwards so you will have to concern yourself with licensing costs if you want to support in the future